# How to maintain states for multiple tabs having same panel Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

How to maintain states for multiple tabs having same panel Components. For example, on tab1 it shows user1 details, on tab2 it shows user2 details. But when I click on tab2 details or inner components it also happen on tab1 because of same redux state. How to manage different state? Maybe on basis of tab index? Or whatever you could suggest.

```
<Tabs
  onChange={handleCurrentPatient}
  value={currentPatient}
  variant="scrollable"
  scrollButtons="auto"
  textColor="primary"
  indicatorColor="primary"
>
  <Tab label="Patients" />
  {dynTabs.map((patient, ind) => (
    <Tab
      label={patient.patientName}
      onClick={() => {
        dispatch(SetCurrentPatient(patient.emrId));
      }}
      value={patient.emrId}
      key={ind}
      icon={
        patient.closeIcon ? (
          <Box onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
            <CloseIcon
              // fontSize="small"
              style={{ fontSize: "16px" }}
            />
          </Box>
        ) : (
          ""
        )
      }
      iconPosition="end"
    />
  ))}
</Tabs>;
{
  dynTabs.map((item2, index) =>
    item2.emrId == currentPatient ? (
      PatientList.map((item1, key2) =>
        currentPatient == item1.emrId ? ( // tab body of current active tab
          <TabPanel key={key2} value={index} index={index}>
            <PatientInfo data={item1}></PatientInfo>
            <Divider sx={{ borderTop: 1, borderTopColor: "#186ad1" }} />
            <PatientRecordTabs />
          </TabPanel>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )
      )
    ) : (
      <>{dynTabs.length == 0 ? setCurrentPatient("000") : <></>}</>
    )
  );
}
```

I want different states for same tab panel components on basis of tab id or index whatever. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your code snippet to include the rest of your component code.